# Unable to identify PageObjects when calling second time

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Below is the page object framework we are using in automating our GUI test cases using selenium.
Here is the scenario I need to do in GUI .
1.  Login to home page 
2.  Click on a link to open the query page 
3.  Enter value in text box and click on Query button
4.  Close this page
5.  Again click on link to open query page
6.  Enter value in text box  and click on query button
7.  Close this page

Here I created PageObjects for Text box and Query button.
A reusable action is created to open the page by clicking on link and enter the value in text box and click on query and close the page.

My issue is that when I call the reusable action first time , its all working fine. When I call the reusable action second time it is not identifying the text box or query button.
Why is it so?

My testcase looks like this.

**Testcase :**

```
public class TC_01 extends BaseClass{
LoginApp login=new LoginApp();
GUIPageActions spa = new GUIPageActions();
login.loginTest();

spa.queryByTN(firstTN,"xyz"); // It is all working fine
spa.queryByTN(TN,"abc"); // Here pageObjects are not identified.

}
```

**Reusable actions:**
GUIPageActions.java File

```
GUIQueryPage soaSubP=new GUIQueryPage (driver);
public void queryByTN(String TN,String status) throws InterruptedException{
//opening page
soaSubP.setTN(TN);
soaSubP.clickQuery();
driver.close();
//closing that page.
}
```

**PageObjects:** 
GUIQueryPage.java 
// PageObjects are created for edit box  and Query button

```
@FindBy(id="fromTn")
@CacheLookup
WebElement fromTn;

@FindBy(id="queryButton")
@CacheLookup
WebElement QueryButton;

public void setTN(String TN){
        fromTn.clear();
        fromTn.sendKeys(TN);
}
public void clickQuery(){
wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("queryButton")));
QueryButton.click();
}
```

Comment: if the driver is closed, how would you expect the script to continue?

Comment: Could you remove the `@CacheLookup` from your PageObject and try again?

Comment: home page is still open  , I am closing only the GUI query page. After that i am moving cursor pointing to home page. From there is able to click the link and open the GUIquery page again.I will try by removing cachelookup